# Cross Domain http get requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I need to make a cross domain ajax call to a server I own but the problem is that the request must come from the client not the server so proxies wont work for me.  Our server will be behind a vpn so it won't be able to reach the internet but the client will be able to so we wanted to do a call home from the client to our metrics server to validate a product key.

My remote domain has a php script that simply writes either a 0, 1, or 2.  I need my javascript to read this value in and react to it.

I want to do something simple like this but clearly it won't work.  Any suggestions?

```
            $.ajax({
                url: callHomeUrl,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(res) {
                    document.write($(res.responseText).text());
                }
            });
```

Comment: If you control the server you need to look into implementing CORS

Comment: Can you use JSONP? `dataType : "jsonp"`

Comment: Antony, using jsonp just causes the page to load forever without doing anything unfortunately.

Comment: @FuegoFingers — It shouldn't do. (Assuming you actually use JSONP as your data source and you don't just tell your JavaScript to try to treat your `0`, `1` or `2` as if it was JSONP).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSONP style implementation for that to get access to your server which works across all browser without CORS!

Example -

```
var script=document.createElement('script'):
   script.type='text/javascript'; script.src='path/to/the/file';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Note that the file in the server should output the javascript function along with any relevant data.